# How do you breakdown ただけなので in 打ち上げただけなので

Tags: grammar

Does the 打ち上げただけなので breakdown into this: ただけなので＝ただ＋だけだ＋なので？

Comment: 打ち上げた verb in past tense + だけ just + なので because

Answer (score 0):

No, it breaks down into 打ち上げた + だけ + なので

打ち上げた is a verb and has several shades of meaning, it's difficult to tell what it means here exactly without further context. だけ means "only/just", and 打ち上げただけ simply means "launching off only". ので is a transition particle and means "due to/because of/by"(you can regard it as being composed of the 代名詞「の」 and で, te-form of だ), and since だけ is a noun and  needs to connect to another noun, that is, the の, you need the な there. Consider 打ち上げただけ as a modifying relative clause that modifies the の.

> 打ち上げた だけ なので...

> By just launching off (something)...

Comment: I'm not sure this の is a 代名詞.

Comment: @aguijonazo I meant the 代名詞 の as opposed to the possessive particle の. The の as in 走る**の**はダメ or 持ってきた**の**は君がいい. I thought 代名詞 would be the right word for this.

Comment: @aguijonazo Oh I see what you mean. The reason I say the の in ので is the 代名詞 is because how it function with relative clauses -- just like a regular 代名詞の. For example, this is how 名詞・形容動詞、形容詞、動詞 connect to 代名詞の: あいつ学生なの？今日寒いの？もう食べたの？And this is how 名詞・形容動詞、形容詞、動詞 connect to ので: あいつ学生なので…今日寒いので…もう食べたので…

Comment: A 代名詞 is a pronoun, it is never used as a pronoun. The の functions as a 準体助詞 here, It connects to the 連体形 of inflectable words (用言), hence な which is the 連体形 of だ, and lets them function as if they're uninflectable words (体言).